# Programa no muestra ninguna salida

Tags: c++, stdout

Tengo una duda estoy haciendo un programa que me muestre el mayor y el menor de un vector, pero al momento de ejecutar el programa no me muestra nada.

Adjunto código:

```
int main() {
    int mayor = 0;
    int menor = 0;
    int numeros[] = { 10,5,6 };



    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        cin >> numeros[i];

        if (numeros[i] > mayor){  mayor = numeros[i];}
        if (numeros[i] < menor) { menor = numeros[i];}
    }


    cout << "El numero mayor es:  " << mayor << endl;
    cout << "El numero menor es:  " << menor << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Las cantidades tienen que ser definidas no se puede solicitar al usuario. 
cualquier comentario me serviría muchas gracias.

Comment: No veo el main y tienes unas comillas al final que no parecen del código...

Answer (score 2):

No hay problema con la salida en tu código, pero si otros más graves. El primer problema y de mayor envergadura es el desbordamiento de buffer que estás causando:

- Declaras un array de tipo `int` para 3 enteros y lo inicializas:

  ```
  int numeros[] = { 10,5,6 };
  ```

  creas un array con capacidad para tres datos de tipo `int` y le asignas los enteros 10, 5 y 6. Nada malo con ésto, si no fuera por lo siguiente...
- Iteras seis veces en el ciclo `for` e intentas introducir los seis enteros ingresados por el usuario en el array:

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
  {
      cin >> numeros[i];
  }
  ```

  El problema es que el array tiene capacidad para contener tres enteros, a partir de la tercera iteración estás escribiendo en memoria no reservada y asignada para tu array. Este desbordamiento del tamaño asignado a la variable causa que se esté accediendo (o intentando) a memoria que puede ser parte de la asignada a tu proceso y por tanto el comportamiento es impredecible porque modificará datos que no debe o estar siendo utilizada por otro programa o el propio SO lo cual terminará en principio con una violación de acceso (segmentation fault) y la terminación inmediata del programa.

  Si no asignaras valores solo intentaras leer, obviando el error de desbordamiento, los resultados serían erróneos ya que lees memoria que no sabes que contiene.

Además de ésto, tiene un pequeño error de lógica, inicializas el valor mínimo y máximo a 0, si el array solo tiene positivos el mínimo será 0 siempre, si solo tiene negativos el máximo será 0 siempre... O bien asignas como valores iniciales el primer valor del array y a partir de ahí iteras o usas un valor "infinito" como valor inicial (que en este caso vendría a ser el máximo y mínimo valor que un dato de tipo `int` puede almacenar en ese sistema, lo cual puedes conseguir mediante [`std::numeric_limits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) o alternativamente vía [`climits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/climits))

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>


int main(){
    int numeros[5];
    int menor = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
    int mayor = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Ingrese el valor para la posicion " << i << ": ";
        std::cin >> numeros[i];
        if (numeros[i] > mayor)
            mayor = numeros[i];
        if (numeros[i] < menor)
            menor = numeros[i];
    }

    std::cout << "El numero mayor es:  " << mayor << std::endl;
    std::cout << "El numero menor es:  " << menor << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Se ingresen o no los valores por parte del usuario asegurate en todo momento de que al recorrer el array por el método que sea (indizado, aritmética de punteros, etc) no sobrepasas nunca el tamaño asignado. Si además el array está destinado a ser llenado por cualquier método, pero no es seguro que va a asignarse valores a todas las posiciones, inicializalo siempre primero con valores convenientes según el caso.